# Identify which element is currently processed

Tags: java, java-8, observable, rx-java2

I would like to know how can I identify which element in the array is currently being processed. for example
I would like to print the following:

```
e
1
Element1 consumed
e
2
Element2 consumed
e
3
Element2 consumed
```

how can i modify the below code to achieve the given results please.

**code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.just("e1", "e2", "e3");
    stringObservable
    .map(x->x.split(""))//return non-observable
    .flatMap(y->Observable.fromArray(y)//return observable
            .map(n->n))
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .blockingSubscribe(getObserver());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `doOnNext` and `doOnComplete` on the inner sequence that splits your source item:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.just("e1", "e2", "e3");

    stringObservable
    .flatMap(x ->
        Observable.fromArray(x.split(""))
        .doOnNext(n -> 
            System.out.println(n)) // <-------------------- prints each split item
        .map(n->n)
        .doOnComplete(() -> 
            System.out.println(
               "Element " + x + " consumed")) // <--------- end of processing of x
    )
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .blockingSubscribe(getObserver());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at the doOnEach operator, you can do they printing there 
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnEach(rx.functions.Action1)